# python: xpath returns empty list from boxofficemojo.com

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to scrape specific data from each movie's page on BoxOfficeMojo.com using the code below. Unfortunately the xpath returns an empty list. Some posts suggest removing tbody from the xpath, but this also returns an empty list. I used the same code to pull text from Rotten Tomatoes and IMBD and the xpath worked fine. Does anyone know why this is happening and how this can be resolved?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

# Box Office Mojo Scrape
page = requests.get('http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?page=main&id=ateam.htm')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

print tree.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/font/b/text()')
print tree.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/table[2]/tr/td/table[1]/tr/td[2]/table/tr/td/center/table/tr[1]/td/font/b/text()')

# Rotten Tomatoes Scrape
page2 = requests.get('http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/star_wars_episode_vii_the_force_awakens/')
tree2 = html.fromstring(page2.text)

print tree2.xpath('//*[@id="scorePanel"]/div[2]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]/div[1]/span/text()')

# IMDB Scrape
page3 = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/?ref_=nv_sr_1')
tree3 = html.fromstring(page3.text)

print tree3.xpath('//*[@id="overview-top"]/h1/span[1]/text()')
```

Comment: You need to tell us more what you are trying to pull for us to be able to help.  However, even without telling us what you are after, I can see one problem.  The element with id _body_ contains exactly one table and everything else is in that table, but you are asking for the second table under that div.  As there is only one table, you are getting an empty node set.  Thus, your problem occurs with the beginning of your location path `//*[@id="body"]/table[2]`.

Comment: @Matthew I am trying to pull the "Domestic Total Gross" value in the first table: $77,222,099. I am not sure what you mean by there being only one table. When I inspect the html tree there are several tables under <div id="body">.

Comment: Those other tables are contained inside the single table that is contained inside the body div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table containing your desired information is nested inside another table and so on.  Thus trying to get `//*[@id='body']/table[2]` is not going to work as there is only one table in that div (with other tables nested inside).

You can obtain this with the EXTREMELY unwieldy xpath expression

```
//*[@id='body']/table/tr[2]/table/tr/td/table[1]/tr/td[2]/table/tr/td/center/table[1]/tr[1]/td/font/b/text()
```

Notice that the desired information is contained inside a bold tag inside a font tag with the text *Domestic Total Gross:* directly inside the font.  I would use the following to get that information

```
//*[@id='body']//font[starts-with(normalize-space(.),'Domestic Total Gross:')]/b/text()
```

This is also less fragile if the table structures change.

Comment: thank you! Both worked perfectly. The latter was much easier to construct to pull additional information (distributor, genre, budget, etc.). Do you know of any resources that give more insight in how to construct these sorts of xpaths? For instance, I also wanted extract the title of the movie ("The A-Team" in the example above) which has no text that precedes it.

Comment: To get the title, you would need something similar to the long form above, as there is nothing closer to really grab onto, but again, it is very risky if anything changes in the page structure.  Personally, I would grab it from the page title instead.  To extract it that way, we can use `substring-before(/html/head/title,' - Box Office Mojo')`, which gives _The A-Team (2010)_.  To get arid of the year, you can do the additional work in python.

Comment: There should be plenty of XPath tutorials online.  Usually resources for XSLT give great Xpath tutorials as well.  You can try some of the links from the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/info) to get started.

Comment: You can also get the title with `tree.xpath("//*[@id='body']//font[string-length(normalize-space(text()))=0]/b/text()")[0]`, but again, this is risky if the page structure changes.  Grabbing from the page title is much more stable.

Comment: Great, thanks again! And thanks for suggesting the stable approach since I've heard that boxofficemojo.com tends to change the structure of their website. I used the following to pull the movie title from the page title: `tree.xpath(/html/head/title/text())` as you mentioned.